# Converting world space coordinate to screen space coordinate and getting incorrect range of values

Tags: xna, c#, coordinates

I'm attempting to convert from world space coordinates to screen space coordinates.

I have the following code to transform my object position

`Vector3 screenSpacePoint = Vector3.Transform(object.WorldPosition, camera.ViewProjectionMatrix);`

The value does not appear to be in screen space coordinates and is not limited to a [-1, 1] range.

What step have I missed out in the conversion process?

EDIT:

Projection Matrix

---

```
Perspective(game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, nearClipPlaneZ, farClipPlaneZ);

    private void Perspective(float aspect_Ratio, float z_NearClipPlane, float z_FarClipPlane)
    {
        nearClipPlaneZ = z_NearClipPlane;
        farClipPlaneZ = z_FarClipPlane;

        float yZoom = 1f / (float)Math.Tan(fov * 0.5f);
        float xZoom = yZoom / aspect_Ratio;

        matrix_Projection.M11 = xZoom;
        matrix_Projection.M12 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M13 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M14 = 0f;

        matrix_Projection.M21 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M22 = yZoom;
        matrix_Projection.M23 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M24 = 0f;

        matrix_Projection.M31 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M32 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M33 = z_FarClipPlane / (nearClipPlaneZ - farClipPlaneZ);
        matrix_Projection.M34 = -1f;

        matrix_Projection.M41 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M42 = 0f;
        matrix_Projection.M43 = (nearClipPlaneZ * farClipPlaneZ) / (nearClipPlaneZ - farClipPlaneZ);
        matrix_Projection.M44 = 0f;
    }
```

View Matrix

---

```
        // Make our view matrix
        Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(ref orientation, out matrix_View);

        matrix_View.M41 = -Vector3.Dot(Right, position);
        matrix_View.M42 = -Vector3.Dot(Up, position);
        matrix_View.M43 = Vector3.Dot(Forward, position);
        matrix_View.M44 = 1f;

        // Create the combined view-projection matrix
        Matrix.Multiply(ref matrix_View, ref matrix_Projection, out matrix_ViewProj);

        // Update the bounding frustum
        boundingFrustum.SetMatrix(matrix_ViewProj);
```

Comment: you should specify the rendering technology that you are using

Comment: I'm using OpenGL with C++ and DirectX for C#.  I am looking to understand why the projection is not working as expected.  In this case it is not producing the range of values I would be expect while the object in question is moved around inside the view frustum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNA has a built-in function for calculating world-to-screen space coordinates called [Viewport.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.project). It also has the opposite function (Unproject) for turning screen coordinates back into world coordinates (minus the depth value).

As far as why your implementation isn't working, I'm not 100% sure but here's a few ideas:

- You're using Vector3.Transform, but your ViewProjectionMatrix is 4x4, so you may be missing the homogenous W divide. I'm not sure whether Vector3.Transform takes this into account.
- If your object's WorldPosition is outside of the view frustum, its post-projective position won't be in the -1 to 1 range. This is how the GPU knows how to clip polygons that lie partially or fully outside the view frustum.
- The range of -1 to 1 is for the unit cube conversion; it's not actually screen space coordinates in the sense of texturing (0.0 to 1.0) or resolution (0.0 to screen width or height).

EDIT: It definitely looks like you're missing the W divide. Vector3.Transform drops the W component in the value it returns. Transform it like this and see if it works:

```
Vector4 objectPos4 = new Vector4( object.WorldPosition, 1.0f );
Vector4 postProjectivePosition = Vector4.Transform(objectPos4, camera.ViewProjectionMatrix);
float clipSpaceX = postProjectivePosition.X / postProjectivePosition.W;
float clipSpaceY = postProjectivePosition.Y / postProjectivePosition.W;
```

That should get it into the -1 to 1 range you desire.

Comment: I've seen the XNA version via reflection and it pretty much does the same thing.  It doesn't work either with my view * projection matrix.

Comment: _If your object's WorldPosition is outside of the view frustum, its post-projective position won't be in the -1 to 1 range._  I should state that I am moving the object around inside the view frustum and the values are not in range.